# How can I link an issue when am I filling out a pull request form on GitHub?

Tags: github, pull-request

There is a manual https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue
and I cannot complete the 4th step because I cannot find "Linked issues".

[image: Linked issues GitHub Help]

Comment: I believe the reason you're unable to click **Linked Issue** is because you don't have write permission to that repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just write `#issue number` in pull request description to link the isuue

you can also write  `fixes #issue number` `closes #issue number` to automatically close an issue when your pull request is accepted and merged

[image: linked issue]

if you are the owner of the repository you can link an issue by clicking the setting icon in the *Linked Issues* on the right sidebar but if you are an outside contributor then you cant use it to change or link any issue you can only see which issues are linked

Comment: I've seen this option in the manual. But I want pop up like in the 5th step on the picture. :)

Comment: you need to be the owner of the repository to use this feature